# Encrypt every files in every folder in another directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm writing a program that encrypt a folder and each file in the parent folder and in the subfolders. The given directory by the user is the var **path**

The function **Encrypt**: encrypt(inputFilePath, outputFilePath)

```
            Dim split As String() = path.Split("\")
            Dim parentFolder As String = split(split.Length - 1)
            Dim currentPath = DataPath & parentFolder

            IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(currentPath)

            'For each file in the parent folder
            For Each File In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
                Encrypt(File, currentPath & "\" & IO.Path.GetFileName(File))
            Next

            'For each directory in the parent folder
            For Each encDir In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
                For Each encFile In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(encDir)
                    Dim split2 As String() = encDir.Split("\")
                    Dim parentFolder2 As String = split(split.Length - 1)
                    Dim currentpath2 = DataPath & parentFolder2
                    Encrypt(encFile, currentpath2 & "\" & IO.Path.GetFileName(encFile))
                Next
            Next
```

This code works in part, it copy every file but not in the subfolders.
[image]

i want that the directory structure is mantained by the program.
Thanks. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You are only getting the files in the folder, you need to get the directories and files. Encrypt the files, and then call your code again with the subfolder path. Recursion would be a better pattern for this, or at least breaking out processing a folder, into sub functions.

Comment: Your encryption code is irrelevant. You should have made sure that you could access every file and folder you need to before adding any encryption. You need to break your problems down into parts and tackle each part independently. Otherwise you make it harder to address problems by cluttering the code with irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getdirectories?view=netcore-3.1), `FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)` returns only the top level directories.
You should use a different overload of the same function to retrieve the subfolders as well.

```
FileSystem.GetDirectories(path, SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*")
```

Comment: Are folder names likely to match the pattern "*.*"?

Comment: "*.*" is the pattern. I misspelled it in my original answer.

Comment: You would use star-dot-star for files, not folders. Just star would be appropriate for folders.